# Prestashop: changing order status in hookActionOrderStatusUpdate

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'am developing module, which after „Payment Accepted“ state executs it's own process and if everything ok - changes order state to Shipped. For that I'am using hookActionOrderStatusUpdate:

```
public function hookActionOrderStatusUpdate($params)
{
  if($params['newOrderStatus']->id == 2)
        {
           if(!$this->doSomething())
              return false;            
        }
    return /*function for changing order's state*/;
}
```

But problem is, that new order status changes before „Payment Accepted“.
Example:

1. Waiting for bankwire payment
2. Delivered
3. Payment Accepted

Does anyone know how to reslove that problem?
P. S. tried hookActionOrderStatusPostUpdate. PS 1.6.0.9

Answer (score 1):

Please try **displayOrderConfirmation** and **displayPaymentReturn** hooks. These hooks receives an order detail in params variable after making payment.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and I used combination of `hookActionOrderStatusUpdate` and `hookActionOrderHistoryAddAfter`.

Reason for that is that `hookActionOrderHistoryAddAfter` really can add another status after "paid" status. And `hookActionOrderStatusUpdate` adds its before "shipped", but `hookActionOrderHistoryAddAfter` does not know about status which going to be set.
So it does looks like this:

```
class MikolaHooks extends Module
{

    public $newOrderStatusId = NULL;
    public function hookActionOrderStatusUpdate($params) {
       $this->newOrderStatusId = $params['newOrderStatus']->id;
    }

    public function hookActionOrderHistoryAddAfter($params) ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You just can't change the order status into the `actionOrderStatusUpdate` hook.

This problem happen because the hook is executed way before the `OrderHistory` is actually registered into the database due to only one thing:
The function where the hook is executed does not save the `OrderHistory` into the database which is processed by the `->add` or `->addWithemail` methods *-- executed manually from external script*.

Eg [this five lines in the `PaymentModule` class](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/cb00a0c7338251127c20738512e5f87a13f1eee0/classes/PaymentModule.php#L561-L565) :

```php
$new_history = new OrderHistory();
$new_history->id_order = (int) $order->id;

// This line exec the Hook
$new_history->changeIdOrderState((int) $id_order_state, $order, true);

// This line save the OrderState into the database
$new_history->addWithemail(true, $extra_vars);
```

A workaround to this issue would be to use `actionOrderHistoryAddAfter` or `actionObjectOrderHistoryAddAfter` instead.

This was undocumented before [I made a PR to the docs](https://github.com/PrestaShop/docs/pull/914/files) and caused many trouble and misundertanding around this hook.